# A silly confusion using expected value?

Tags: probability, statistics

> Consider a fuse with lifetime $T$, which is exponentially distributed. The fuse can be fabricated by two > processes:
>
> - Process 1: Has an expected lifetime of 100 hours and costs 10 by fuse.
> - Process 2: Has an expected lifetime of 150 hours and costs 20 by fuse.
>
> If a fuse lasts less then 200 hours, the factory will have to pay a fine of 5$.
>
> What process should be used?

I tried the following: I think I should compare the following integrals for expected value:

$$(10+5)\int_{0}^{200} x \cdot \lambda e^{-\lambda x}  \quad \quad \quad  \quad  \quad (20+5)\int_{0}^{200} x \cdot \lambda' e^{-\lambda' x} $$

For both processes. But it's not clear if $\lambda=100$ and $\lambda '=150$ although I believe it is. I guess this would enable us to measure how much money would be lost due to fines plus manufacturing costs. Does that make sense? Sorry if it is too nonsensical, I'm studying on my own.

Comment: Even if the fuse continues to work for $1000$ hours you still incur the cost of manufacturing it. I would use the integral to compute just the expected fine and add this to the known cost of manufacturing.

Comment: If anything, comparing $10+5\int_0^{200}x\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\,dx$ and $20+5\int_0^{200}x\lambda'e^{-\lambda' x}\,dx$ makes more sense. Also, if you use that form for the parameter of the exponential distribution, then $E[T]=\frac1\lambda$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Do you mean it should be $\lambda= \frac{1}{100}$ and $\lambda'= \frac{1}{150}$?

Comment: There are two different parameterizations of exponential distributions--using mean and using rate. Either way you want the CDF.

Comment: There are two different parameterizations of exponential distributions--using mean and using rate. Either way you want the CDF. For example: $P(X \le 200) = 1 - e^{-.01(200)}$ $= 1 - e^{-200/100} = 4.323324.$

Answer (score 1):

The expected fine for a fuse made using the
first process is 4.32.

```
5 * pexp(200, 1/100)
[1] 4.323324
5*(1 - exp(-200/100))
[1] 4.323324
```

The expected fine for a fuse made using the
second process is less, but of course, not
enough less to make up for the additional cost (10)
of making the more durable fuse.

```
5 * pexp(200, 1/150)
[1] 3.682014  
5*(1 - exp(-200/150))
[1] 3.682014
```

---

The cost and fine structure makes no sense:

- Even if a fuse made by the inferior process
  *always* incurred a fine of 5, that would mean a
  total cost
  of 15.
- Thus, if the better fuses *never* incurred
  a fine, they still cost more (20) than the others.

With manufacturing costs 10 and 20, a fine of **50** would be sufficient to encourage
manufacture of the better type of fuses.
With costs 10 and **11,** a fine of 5, would suffice.

*Notes:* (a) If an exponential distribution has mean $\mu = 100,$ then its failure rate is $1/100,$ sometimes designated $\lambda.$ R uses the rate parameterization, hence `5 * pexp(200, 1/100)` in my first bit if R code; followed by
a strictly numeric computation giving the same numerical answer.

(b) I have interpreted "cost by fuse" to mean the manufacturing cost per fuse. If you mean the sales prices per fuse then the net incomes per fuse are 5.68 and 16.32, but that does not make
it clear which type the manufacturer should make,
because we have no idea about costs of production.

```
10 - 5 * pexp(200, 1/100)
[1] 5.676676
20 - 5 * pexp(200, 1/150)
[1] 16.31799
```

Comment: The cost production is 10 and 20 by fuse, no? Do you mean the total cost?

Comment: That was my assumption in the main part of my answer, but then a fine of 5 makes little sense. // I discussed alternative scenarios--only trying to turn it into a problem where the fine makes a difference.

Comment: I would have thought you might have wanted the expected cost per fused hour rather than the expected cost per fuse

Comment: Easy to say offhand. Hard to make sense of when it comes to mgf incentive and decision and effect of fine.  [Presumably mfg pays fine; who get it? govt or customer?)]